# no jdk1.7 but with error Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Tags: eclipse, egit, java-6

I use eclipse with JDK1.6 and webLogic12, also use egit to control source, there is no any JDK1.7 on my PC, but when I start server, I got error as below, what can I do?

```
<2017/11/10 13:31:50 JST> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101371>Error: Class bytes found but defineClass()failed for: 'MyLogin'> 
<2017/11/10 13:31:50 JST> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> Error: Class bytes found but defineClass()failed for: 'MyLogin''
weblogic.application.ModuleException: Error: Class bytes found but defineClass()failed for: 'MyLogin'
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.prepare(WebAppModule.java:732)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.prepare(ScopedModuleDriver.java:188)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:83)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:172)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: MyLogin : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:343)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got answer as below follow [enter link description here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=11052502#11052502)

```
In Servers view, right click on 12c node | Properties 
WebLogic | Publishing, switch to "Publish as an exploded archive" - Click OK
Re-publish your app
```